# Can't include an external library in another header with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project setup with the following folder structure:

- External

  - Boost
  - Poco
- Libraries

  - Lib1

    - src

      - lib1.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - Lib2

    - src
    - CMakeLists.txt
- Projects

  - Project1

    - src
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - Project

    - src
    - CMakeLists.txt
- Public

  - Lib1

    - lib1.h
  - Lib2

Basically I have a folder for external libraries like Poco or Boost. Next to that I have a projects folder. Each project has it own independent source files and have the possibility to include/link one or more of the libs in the Libraries folder. Each library has also a private src folder and a public header folder.

The CMakeLists.txt file of a library looks something like this (${PUBLIC_DIRECTORY} is set to the correct public folder)

```
set(Sources
    "${PUBLIC_DIRECTORY}/lib1.h"
    "src/lib1.cpp"        
)

include_directories("../../External/Boost")
add_library(Lib1 ${Sources})
link_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Lib1")
```

The problem happens when I try to include a boost header  like boost/lexical_cast.hpp.
When I include this in lib1.cpp, everything compiles. But when I do the same in lib1.h, I get the error: boost/lexical_cast.hpp: No such file or directory.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: **1.** What's the relationship between `WebServer.*` and `lib1.*`? **2.** When including it in the `.h`, building which source file and project gives the error?

Comment: my bad, Webserver is actually Lib1. I just changed the names to have some kind of abstraction. I'll edit it

Comment: Thought so ;-) Can you also answer my question 2? I mean, from a compiler's point of view, `.h` files don't really exist - their content is textually pasted into the `.cpp` file, so the only `.cpp` file's settings apply.

Comment: holy crap, you are right. It was the main.cpp (that included lib1.h) that was giving the error. By including boost into the main project, the error was solved.

Answer (score 3):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

When you `#include "boost/..."` in a `.h` file, make sure that all projects which use that `.h` file are correctly configured to use Boost. Bear in mind that from a compiler's point of view, `.h` files don't really exist - their content is textually pasted into the `.cpp` file, so only the `.cpp` file's settings (such as include paths) apply.